# How do I change the target of Process.Start during runtime?

Tags: c#

So how can I make button2, change the targeted .exe of button1?

```
//button1 is below me
public void OpenEXE1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
Process.Start("D:\\Firefox\\firefox.exe");
}
 
 // button2 is below me
private void ChangeTarget1(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{ 
//I want this stuff here to change the target of button1 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the target inline, store it in a variable, a change it when the button is clicked.

```
protected string _target = "D:\\Firefox\\firefox.exe";

public void OpenEXE1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Process.Start(_target);
}

private void ChangeTarget1(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{ 
    _target = "d:\\SomeOtherTarget";
}
```

Comment: I tried that. I tested it by clicking button2 to change the target, then pressing button1 to execute. I got "The system cannot find the specified file" error.

Comment: Sounds like it worked! And whatever you set the target to was a file that doesn't exist....

Comment: But the file does exist though, I've confirmed that.